# mysql functions concept

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concept

I am new to MySQL and PHP. One thing I'm unable to understand that when we check a given condition in if/else statement. Is the opposite of that condition runs automatically ?

I mean:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
    if (!$link)
    {
    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
    }
?>
```

Here mysqli_connect is a function and to connect we have to run the function. So the misconception here is that how it is connecting to the server. Since i havn't run the mysqli_function separately. I mean there should be a separate line for that.

OR the opposite of a given condition runs automatically ?

Comment: You've called `mysqli_connect` in order to connect, where's the problem here?

Comment: Of topic, but: **PLEASE indent your code**

Comment: I have declared mysqli_connect in a variable. How its running.

Comment: Cleared OK. I thought by just assigning a function inside a variable will not make it run and we have to run it separately. I was wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have declared mysqli_connect in a variable.

No, you haven't.

You have called `mysqli_connect` and assigned its return value to a variable.

The [manual says](http://php.net/mysqli_connect):

> Returns an object which represents the connection to a MySQL Server.

If the connection fails, that that will be a falsey value (which the `if` statement checks, so it will only do some things if the connection was successful).

Comment: Great man Thanks a lot. I though we can't call a function inside a variable it just assigns.. I was wrong